# Stuck installing apk... Android

Tags: android

I'm making a game for Android and successfully installed the first apk.
But now everytime I try to install a new one it gets stuck on "Installing Space Racer.apk..."
Any help?

Comment: What is the size of your apk?

Comment: are you installing using eclipse and right clicking on the project or using the command line. Using either one it should give an error. If your install using the cmd promot you will need to add the -r after installing it the first time i.e adb -d install -r myapp.apk

Comment: You need to provide more details. Error messages, from where you're trying to install, which options. You won't get far here if you don't provide enough details. Just saying...

Comment: You could go as well and uninstall your game manually from your device, and the try to install it again from eclipse, by compiling and running the application.